# (discord.py) Cannot import DefaultAvatar from discord.enums

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot on replit and it was working but then i kept getting an error saying `ImportError: Cannot import name 'DefaultAvatar' from 'discord.enums'` I have tried looking for other people with the same problem but nobody does. I have tried looking for the error in the package itself on github but it's there.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no enums module in discord.py.
If you look at the source code, the enums module is only present in the legacy version.

Comment: It was working yesterday but now its not so i know i am using the right one.